# Pass Python bytes to C/C++ function using swig?

Tags: python, c++, c, swig

How do you pass a `bytes` value from Python (like data loaded from a file with `open('my file.dat', 'rb').read()`) to a C/C++ function using `swig`?

When I try using `char *` or `uint8_t *` and then a `size` parameter it gives me an error like this:

```
TypeError: in method 'processData', argument 3 of type 'char *'
```

I've tried using `%pybuffer_mutable_binary` and `%pybuffer_binary` but they don't seem to change the definition of the wrapper and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Without code can't diagnose what is wrong, but likely you didn't declare `%pybuffer` lines **before** the function definitions.  If declared after the generated wrappers won't use them when processing the functions, which would explain "they don't seem to change the definition of the wrapper".

Here's a working example.  Note that passing an *immutable* item to a function that modifies the string will crash Python.  It would be nice if the commands from `pybuffer.i` type-checked the Python object for mutability.  If you want that don't use `pybuffer.i`.

**test.i**

```c
%module test

%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
%}

%include <pybuffer.i>
%pybuffer_mutable_string(char* str1)
%pybuffer_string(const char* str2)
%pybuffer_mutable_binary(char* str3, size_t size)
%pybuffer_binary(const char* str4, size_t size)

%inline %{
void funcms(char *str1) {
    strupr(str1);
}

size_t funcs(const char *str2) {
    return strlen(str2);
}

void funcmb(char* str3, size_t size) {
    memset(str3,'A',size);
}

size_t funcb(const char* str4, size_t size) {
    size_t tmp = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        tmp += str4[i];
    return tmp % 256;
}
%}
```

Demo:

```py
>>> import test
>>> b=bytearray(b'abc')  # mutable string (nul-terminated)
>>> test.funcms(b)
>>> b
bytearray(b'ABC')
>>> test.funcs(b'abc')   # immutable string (nul-terminated)
3
>>> b=bytearray(b'ab\0cd\0ef')  # mutable data (includes nulls)
>>> test.funcmb(b)
>>> b
bytearray(b'AAAAAAAA')
>>> test.funcb(b'ab\0cd\0ef')   # immutable data (compute byte checksum)
85
>>> sum(b'ab\0cd\0ef')%256      # verify result
85
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is a type map using the Python buffer interface. This passes a pointer to your data to the C/C++ function without any copying of data. For example:

```
%typemap(in, numinputs=1) (const char *data, unsigned long int size) {
  Py_buffer view;
  if (PyObject_CheckBuffer($input) != 1) {
    PyErr_SetString(
      PyExc_TypeError,
      "in method '$symname', argument $argnum does not support the buffer interface");
    SWIG_fail;
  }
  if (PyObject_GetBuffer($input, &view, PyBUF_SIMPLE) != 0) {
    PyErr_SetString(
      PyExc_TypeError,
      "in method '$symname', argument $argnum does not export a simple buffer");
    SWIG_fail;
  }
  $1 = view.buf;
  $2 = view.len;
  PyBuffer_Release(&view);
}
%typemap(doc) const char *data, unsigned long int size "$1_name: readable buffer (e.g. bytes)"
```