# Multiple byte "OUTPUT" arguments in SWIG?

Tags: python, swig, swig-typemap

I've got a C library which has 3 functions (all arguments are fixed-length `uint8_t*`, with the length known at compile time):

- One which has 2 output parameters only
- One which has 1 input parameter and 2 output parameters
- One which has 2 input parameters and 1 output parameter

I'm trying to create SWIG-based Python bindings for this C library, but they don't seem to work. Even after importing `typemaps.i`, swig still complains that **a `bytearray` is inappropriate for a `uint8_t INOUT[]` argument when trying to call the function.**

I don't get it. What am I doing wrong?

https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/Python.html#Python_nn46

> Notice how the `INPUT` parameters allow integer values to be passed instead of pointers and how the `OUTPUT` parameter creates a return result.
>
> If you don't want to use the names `INPUT` or `OUTPUT`, use the %apply directive.

It doesn't look like `%pybuffer_mutable_binary` is the right choice, since it *requires* a size parameter, and my interface doesn't *have* one.

---

### Appendix: code

#### SWIG module

```
%module "libmceliece6960119f_clean"
%include "typemaps.i"

%{
// https://github.com/PQClean/PQClean/blob/fb003a2a625c49f3090eec546b2383dcfa2c75d8/crypto_kem/mceliece6960119f/clean/api.h
#include "api.h"
%}

int PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_crypto_kem_keypair(
    uint8_t INOUT[PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_CRYPTO_PUBLICKEYBYTES],
    uint8_t INOUT[PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_CRYPTO_SECRETKEYBYTES]);

int PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_crypto_kem_enc(
    uint8_t INOUT[PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_CRYPTO_CIPHERTEXTBYTES],
    uint8_t INOUT[PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_CRYPTO_BYTES],
    const uint8_t INPUT[PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_CRYPTO_PUBLICKEYBYTES]);

int PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_crypto_kem_dec(
    uint8_t INOUT[PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_CRYPTO_BYTES],
    const uint8_t INPUT[PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_CRYPTO_CIPHERTEXTBYTES],
    const uint8_t INPUT[PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_CRYPTO_SECRETKEYBYTES]);
```

#### Usage (broken)

```py
_libmceliece6960119f_clean.PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_crypto_kem_keypair()
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_crypto_kem_keypair expected 2 arguments, got 0

pk, sk = bytearray(1047319), bytearray(13948); _libmceliece6960119f_clean.PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_crypto_kem_keypair(pk, sk)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: in method 'PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_crypto_kem_keypair', argument 1 of type 'uint8_t [PQCLEAN_MCELIECE6960119F_CLEAN_CRYPTO_PUBLICKEYBYTES]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created a typemap, you need a typemap.

There are examples for this typemap in the SWIG documentation, you should use the `pybuffer.i` typemaps.

This answer has an example: [Pass Python bytes to C/C++ function using swig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022652/pass-python-bytes-to-c-c-function-using-swig)